# How to reflect changes in the module object to module file in python

Tags: python, module

I am importing a module in python, and initializing some extra attributes for that module object. Is it possible that those extra attributes to be reflected in corresponding files without editing those files directly.

Comment: This is not easily achievable.

Comment: Could you achieve a similar effect by having your module read and write from a separate configuration file? Perhaps using something simple like pickle or json, or something more standard like https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Comment: @TomDalton Yeah, that is a very good way to get away with this problem. But it will obscure readability. Anyways it will suffice my need for current working, so if you write this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks. If you want to re-ask the question, or add some more detail on exactly what those attributes are, or what they're for, it might be easier to suggest an even better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you achieve a similar effect by having your module read and write from a separate configuration file? Perhaps using something simple like pickle or json, or something more standard like docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html